# cannot getDocumentById on dynamically created input id's

Tags: javascript

I have the following html

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="refNumber in Dc.Data">
        <td>
            {{refNumber.label}}: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td ng-if="refNumber.isFlowerRequired && refNumber.value != null">
            <input type="text" id="{{refNumber.refId}}" ng-value="refNumber.value != null ? refNumber.value : ''" />
        </td>
        <td ng-if="refNumber.isFlowerRequired && refNumber.value == null">
            <input type="text" id="{{refNumber.refId}}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the `refNumber.refId` is a GUID (fd74cea6-ebe4-4085-b221-70c41624bc1b
).

I have my code setup the following way

```
for (var i = 0; i < Dc.Data.filter(val => val.isRequired).length; i++) {
    var refNumText = document.getElementById("'"+ Dc.Data[i].refId + "'").value;
    console.log(refNumText);
}
```

I am running into `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

Searching online gave some pointers but nothing has helped me solve this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: reason to close?

Comment: You have duplicate `id="{{refnumber.refId}}"`. IDs should be unique.

Comment: `"'"+ Dc.Data[i].refId + "'"` should probably be `Dc.Data[i].refId`.

Comment: @connexo, tried that. Returns the same error.

Comment: @connexo seems to be right, if this doesn't help, can you post your html after it's been generated (including IDs)?

Comment: @Barmar Check the `ng-if`, only either of them can be generated.

Comment: @Walk, how do I do that. I am sorry I did not understand it. 
I can get the text if I do the following `getDocumentById("abcd-123-gefh-23').value`

Comment: @Barmar. ids are unique. I checked that.

Comment: @connexo, trying the following way
`var refNumText = document.getElementById(Dc.Data[i].refId).value;` returns the same error.

Comment: basic debugging,  try logging  Dc && Dc.Data && Dc.Data[i] && Dc.Data[i].refId - then look at the data that prints out.

Comment: @Maddy I noticed that you `filter` your array to use in a loop but then you're using original array inside of it. Try `var refNumText = document.getElementById(Dc.Data.filter(val => val.isRequired)[i].refId).value;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding quotes around the refId when calling `document.getElementById()`. There are no quotes in the UIDs.

You're filtering `Dc.Data` to just the elements with `isRequired` set. But you're just using that to get the number of iterations, you're not actually processing those same elements. You should iterate over the filtered array.

```
Dc.Data.filter(val => val.isRequired).forEach(d => {
    var refNumText = document.getElementById(d.refId).value;
    console.log(refNumText);
});
```

Comment: `var refNumText = document.getElementById(Dc.Data[i].refId).value;` returns the same error. This is the reason I am confused.
I am happy to provide more info but not sure what to add.

Comment: You're not processing the elements with `isRequred` set correctly. I've updated the answer.